# additional row colors in seaborn cluster map

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am currently generating clustermaps in seaborn and labeling the row colors as below.

```
matrix = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_integers(0,1, size=(50,4)))
labels = np.random.random_integers(0,5, size=50)

lut = dict(zip(set(labels), sns.hls_palette(len(set(labels)), l=0.5, s=0.8)))
row_colors = pd.DataFrame(labels)[0].map(lut)

g=sns.clustermap(matrix, col_cluster=False, linewidths=0.1, cmap='coolwarm', row_colors=row_colors)
plt.show()
```

I have a second annotation column similar to the labels data I would also like to add to the plot. The seaborn API doesn't support adding a second `row_colors` column, which is fine, but I am struggling in finding a workaround using matplotlib to add this annotation column to the clustering.

If I cannot use seaborn to do this and have to generate all of this manually using matplotlib that would be fine, I just can't figure that out either.

Thanks for your help!

[image: clustermap example plot]

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? How would the second row_colors be integrated into the plot, where would it appear?

Comment: In regards to the clustermap example plot I provided in the question, what I want to add to that is another 'row colors' column right next to the first one (the multi-colored column on the clustermap plot). To the right or left it doesn't really matter, I just would like to add another color code to the row. I dont specifically need the dendograms on the plot, so it would be alright to plot it another way without those if that made it possible.

Comment: Actually this problem is solved. The seaborn API DOES, in fact, support adding a second row of color labels. Creating a second set of variables as above for the labels, lut, and row_colors  as above, and passing both of those to the row_colors argument as a list in sns.clustermap does indeed work.

Comment: If you have found a solution, please provide it as answer to the question, such that the question is solved and it will be useful for other people. Best provide a [mcve], such that people can reproduce the solution.

Comment: Thanks! I went ahead and added the answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The solution is below. The seaborn API does actually allow this to be done.

```
matrix = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_integers(0,1, size=(50,4)))

labels = np.random.random_integers(0,5, size=50)
lut = dict(zip(set(labels), sns.hls_palette(len(set(labels)), l=0.5, s=0.8)))
row_colors = pd.DataFrame(labels)[0].map(lut)

#Create additional row_colors here
labels2 = np.random.random_integers(0,1, size=50)
lut2 = dict(zip(set(labels2), sns.hls_palette(len(set(labels2)), l=0.5, s=0.8)))
row_colors2 = pd.DataFrame(labels2)[0].map(lut2)

g=sns.clustermap(matrix, col_cluster=False, linewidths=0.1, cmap='coolwarm', row_colors=[row_colors, row_colors2])
plt.show()
```

This produces a Clustermap with two additional columns:
[image: Clustermap with two additional columns]

Comment: If you pass a DataFrame instead of a list to row_colors, the column names are displayed

Answer (score 14):

I tried to concat the row_colors dataframe by pandas and it worked!
Please try this code:

```
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(color_codes=True)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
print(iris)
species = iris.pop("species")


lut1 = dict(zip(species.unique(), ['#ED2323','#60FD00','#808080']))
row_colors1 = species.map(lut1)

lut2 = dict(zip(species.unique(), "rbg"))
row_colors2 = species.map(lut2)

row_colors = pd.concat([row_colors1,row_colors2],axis=1)
print(row_colors)

g = sns.clustermap(iris, row_colors=row_colors, col_cluster=False,cmap="mako", yticklabels=False, xticklabels=False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This keeps the labels as well!

Answer (score 0):

There is another option for feeding in the annotation colors: you can provide a whole dataframe in the row colors or col_colors options, instead of a list of lists.

This strategy might be particularly helpful if you have a dataframe with several annotations you want represented. Instead of map, you can use the pandas function replace.

Something such as this bit can be used to modify the other answer:

```
## This step is necessary because you can't use replace with the tuple rgb values
lut = {k:matplotlib.colors.to_hex(v) for k, v in lut.iteritems()}

annotations_df = annotations_df.replace(lut)

g=sns.clustermap(matrix, col_cluster=False, linewidths=0.1, cmap='coolwarm', row_colors=annotations_df)
plt.show()
```