# add more space to the color_row in sns.clustermap

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

How to add more spacing to column/row_colors? It looks it gets really dense after adding 3 or more rows

```
#modified example data is from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48173798/additional-row-colors-in-seaborn-cluster-map

matrix = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_integers(0,1, size=(50,4)))

labels = np.random.random_integers(0,5, size=50)
lut = dict(zip(set(labels), sns.hls_palette(len(set(labels)), l=0.5, s=0.8)))

row_colors = pd.DataFrame(labels)[0].map(lut)

#Create additional row_colors here
labels2 = np.random.random_integers(0,1, size=50)
lut2 = dict(zip(set(labels2), sns.hls_palette(len(set(labels2)), l=0.5, s=0.8)))
row_colors2 = pd.DataFrame(labels2)[0].map(lut2)

# add more rows
row_colors = pd.concat([row_colors,row_colors,row_colors2,row_colors2,row_colors2],axis=1)

g=sns.clustermap(matrix, col_cluster=False, linewidths=0.1, cmap='coolwarm', row_colors=row_colors)
plt.show()
```

[cluster_example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHj5s.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the `linewidths` parameter.

`g=sns.clustermap(matrix, col_cluster=False, linewidths=0.9, cmap='coolwarm', row_colors=row_colors)` will give you more spacing.

[image]

Comment: Well it only works with the actual heatmap. I don't see you get too much separation with the row_colors in this case? Plus the labels are still unreadable

Comment: Did you try it with different values? @Timo